# Jenkinsfile - Copy from Stage's Steps's Container to another Container

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, devops, jenkins-groovy

I want to copy file which is created in one container to another in Jenkinsfile.

```
stage('BUILD:') {
    stages {
        stage('First Stage') {
            container('firstcontainer') {
                sh "touch newFile.txt"
            }
            container('secondcontainer') {
                //I want to access that file here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As show in above example, I have created file newFile.txt in firstcontainer and I want to copy that into secondcontainer.

Comment: For small files (up to 5MB) you can use the [stash](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#stash-stash-some-files-to-be-used-later-in-the-build) keyword to stash the files from one container workspace and unstash it to the other one.

Comment: Hi @NoamHelmer, thanks for the reply, but files are many and size is also big. Any way to do it?

Comment: You can check out the [External Workspace Manager](https://plugins.jenkins.io/external-workspace-manager/) plugin, which is design for easily sharing files across jobs or stages.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Persistent Volume defined with your `podTemplate` that both containers can access.

However if you need two containers to access the same file it's logical to question if there is a need to access the file to begin with.